# Show the uniqueness of zero

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Let g: $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be twice differentiable. Suppose $g(0)=1/2$, $g'(0)=1$, $|g''(x)| \le 1 $ $\forall x \in[-1,1]$. There's an $a\in [-1,0)$ satisfying $g(a)=0$. Show uniqueness of such a zero.

I want to show $g$ is monotonic, then this implies uniqueness, but I'm stuck on showing there's unique zero on the interval as well. Thanks.

Comment: What is the relevance of the existence of the sequence $a_n$?

Comment: @dREaM It might be redundant because I derived it from other parts of the problem and not sure if it's useful in proving the result.

Comment: Tell me if you need help working out the details.

Comment: This question is sort of strange, you can prove there is a unique zero without using the existence of $a_n$ though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$g'(x)>0$ for all $x\in(-1,1)$. Otherwise use the mean value theorem to contadict $|g''(x)|\leq 1$.

Once you know this, assume $g(x)=g(y)$ with $x,y\in [-1,1]$ and use the mean value theorem to obtain a contradiction.

Therefore $g$ is injective in the interval $[-1,0)$. This combined with the fact there is an $a\in [-1,0)$ with $g(a)=0$ tells use there is exactly one element in $[-1,0]$ which maps to zero, as was desired.

Comment: Thanks, do I need to show there's $a \in [-1,0)$ with $g(a)=0$? Did you derive from the fact that {$a_n$} approach a limit $a \in [-1,0)$ satisfying $g(a)=0$？

Comment: Yes, I derived the existence of such an $a$ from the sequence.

Comment: Or is that hypothesis wrong or something?

Comment: It is right that there's a fast convergence for the sequence {$a_n$} to approach a limit  $a \in [-1,0)$ satisfying $f(a)=0$. If the sequence approach a limit $a\in [-1,0)$ such that $f(a)=0$, then there's $a \in [-1,0)$ satisfying $f(a)=0$? Is this intuitive or do I need more steps to show this?

Comment: Hmm, why don't you edit the question so that it is exactly equal to what you have to prove?

Comment: I've edited it, I'm just confused if I need to show $g(a)=0$

Comment: No, you don't. It clearly states $a\in [-1,0]$ with $g(a)=0$.

Comment: Could you explain how you applied MVT to $g(x)=g(y)$ with $x,y \in [-1,1]$ and obtained contradiction?

Comment: sure, suppose $g(x)=g(y)$. then by the median value theorem there is a point $z\in(x,y)$ with $g'(z)=0$. this is a contradiction because we know if $z\in (-1,1)$ then $g(z)>0$.

Comment: You mean we know if $z\in (-1,1)$ then $g'(z)>0$?

Comment: Yeah, my bad, thanks for catching that.